# Firebase Notification duplicated message

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a serious issue, I am receiving multiple push notifications.
I found it generated lots of registration token.
These token were made by the same one person, use same desktop, on same network domain.I have try to send test message to those tokens.And those tokens work.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab330e1a8dbc4623df77853"),
    "token" : "d8DtmhvF4_c:APA91bEaGFkn-g2B0-dpOIxfgrvfVbXiB-mLiRPaVfQpGlo4vSYC_FHJfnyQWzLnYmU9CWHqpX1rx1nR7YM7msd5umooOXPXS3dHY9QdQl0NlIkdJ8HQJth1NKPTMy7DhV9HPFrBDQvm",
    "agent" : "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/65.0.3325.181 safari/537.36",
    "status" : "enable",
    "session" : "89196faa-df82-1e0f-b36b-2854ed3c7b95",
    "time" : "2018-03-22 12:28:17"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab9b593403ab4ac0f777a63"),
    "token" : "fu-CQUJz8VA:APA91bEn0L-U14Nz0x9nw-Ck3UXbT6CeXpYJZTFBPYCfRH3eGyez3__O6GzA_isY_M_tJiKgofIXrrfhc66tBtiv1ffZ34kuQTe8Qh8oDg43zNo1HSJbQebR1WuMm3P7i28RROTaUpC2",
    "agent" : "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/65.0.3325.181 safari/537.36",
    "session" : "89196faa-df82-1e0f-b36b-2854ed3c7b95",
    "status" : "enable",
    "time" : "2018-03-27 11:08:03"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abc6b6ebf33dee27bc0ccd5"),
    "token" : "d8DtmhvF4_c:APA91bFUSmTLhe5RHwPBkpUIZCsqzxBjH7yf6HBcmj709xZVG8LaJ07XZTbIZrumb2rKXJ_V9IM6ez6rSKuZqT6iuwRScNEzNQ_CS3Kvcwgp4xrf2VHkYVF5uW7gzF3tq7_izdxwYvvl",
    "agent" : "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/65.0.3325.181 safari/537.36",
    "status" : "enable",
    "session" : "89196faa-df82-1e0f-b36b-2854ed3c7b95",
    "time" : "2018-03-29 12:28:30"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5acab503a94c4152379c6983"),
    "token" : "d8DtmhvF4_c:APA91bFKKQox-DMLej4Mf2zdUfpE3MR0ew48i7lJ-iX7mMskp4KhCJPIhzYsTH88YZXC2FhkLJuUBOsa086Z5OLZ-jU0XFRJz4i2BJI5gWxVa5Npkd5fLsWo4t2nBTdNOZra0SD0gdXb",
    "agent" : "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/65.0.3325.181 safari/537.36",
    "status" : "enable",
    "session" : "89196faa-df82-1e0f-b36b-2854ed3c7b95",
    "time" : "2018-04-09 08:34:11"
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad3efbeb98df3232dfc7fb3"),
    "token" : "d8DtmhvF4_c:APA91bHsynAV6riwAF4statZxwMt5YJUN19zCd44HRoxp9AOoLwCTG4yrq-aX5UA7ik1UB2H5l30GIYXSqaAqcOYQwyio4jMZF7-SeJ-KR6_LtqlIVNQOuRrvWpW5EAnjWyyhrX3A3rh",
    "agent" : "mozilla/5.0 (windows nt 6.1; win64; x64) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/65.0.3325.181 safari/537.36",
    "status" : "enable",
    "session" : "89196faa-df82-1e0f-b36b-2854ed3c7b95",
    "time" : "2018-04-16 08:35:10"
}
```

Any suggestion will be helpful for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Firebase. We fixed it recently, and it should not happen anymore. The SDK will keep using the same token as long as it is valid, and will not generate extra tokens unless the current token is revoked.

As the previously generated tokens are still valid, you'll have to remove the extra tokens (that are from the same user) from your server.